# UITableView not reloading data after model data changes (cellForRowAtIndexPath not fired)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

For the app I'm currently working on, one of my main ViewControllers contains two UITableViews whose contents vary based on what's stored in my model (Core Data backed by SQL).  Both tableviews set their delegate and datasource properties to the shared VC they're both subviews of, and I provide the necessary methods in the VC to respond to tableview-specific events.

I'm finding that when I add new data to my database that should cause the TableViews to show new rows, and I return to the VC and call reloadData on both TableViews in the VC's viewWillAppear method, I see that **numberOfRowsInSection** returns the correct number of rows based on the new entries in CoreData, but **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is not called the correct number of times, almost like it's not responding to the change in the model data.  For example, if I had 3 rows to show then the app started, and I added another entry in CoreData, then called reloadData, **numberOfRowsInSection** returns 4 correctly, but **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is only called 3 times still.

Besides the fact that I probably be using something more suitable like NSFetchedResultsController to link my TableViews to CoreData, is there any reason why **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is not being called the correct number of times, as dictated by the correct number of rows returned by **numberOfRowsInSection**?

I would put in some of my code, but it's really standard boilerplate TableView stuff and I feel like there's something else that I'm missing.

Comment: do put in some code for both cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection... that would really help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure you understand correctly, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called with the number of cell that can be in the screen. If you have 4 cells, but because the height of the cell, only 3 cells can be available to users, then the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called 3 times

Comment: My problem was that the UITableViews were being added as subviews to a UIScrollView, and the size of that UIScrollView was not being adjusted properly to expand to fit larger tables.  I wasn't thinking about the problem properly, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

If the user can only see only 3 cells, not more, then the cell loading callbacks may only be called 3 times, even if there are 100's of rows in your table.